# How to position the plot legend outside the plot in the bottom-right

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the latest ggplot2 and currently do `p + theme(legend.position='right')`. The function [theme is well documented](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) and combining `bottom` and `right` doesn't seem possible. However, maybe there is an alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: the dev version of ggplot2 has better control over this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use 2-element numeric vector for the position, something like:

```
p+theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0)
```

**The problem is**, it will overlap the plotting area.

And if you want to force it to be in one horizontal line, you can add:

```
p+guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

[image: output]

**EDIT**

I used plot.margin to expand the area at the bottom, you can play with the parameters:

```
p+
 guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))+
 theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,4,0.5),"cm"))+
 theme(legend.position=c(0.85,-0.7))
```

[image]

OR

```
  p+
     theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,4,0.5),"cm")) +
     theme(legend.position=c(0.85,-0.7))
```

[image]

**NOTE**

Using Rstudio, when I export the image at certain width*height I don't get the legends, but if I drag and adjust the view before exporting as follows, it works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! good to know! but I really need the legend outside the plotting area ... what happens if you do 1.3 instead of 0.85??

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I edited the answer, plz check if this what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you again! I tried it, but I can't get the legend where I want. When I specify the coordinates outside the plot width the legend disappears.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I added a note, maybe if you try to adjust it manually it will work.

Comment: Thank you good job! but for me is all automatic ... no UI interaction to play with the view.

Comment: Nice answer. You can get your plot margins from the theme thus: ``theme_bw()$plot.margin`` ``##5.5pt 5.5pt 5.5pt 5.5pt``. In my case, with a custom theme, my units were ``unit(c(1,1,1,1), "lines")`` and I tweaked them to ``unit(c(1,1,3,1), "lines")`` with great effect.